# wget over proxy within Dockerfile doesn't work

Tags: docker, proxy, docker-compose, wget

i have an server that have access internet only via proxy.

So im using this docker-compose command:

```
docker-compose build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.server:3128 --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy.server:3128 web
```

It starts to download alpine-os Image, executes commands like apk add, fetch from internet, which works.

Except downloading wget don't works:

```
wget -O libiconv.tar.gz "https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-$LIBICONV_VERSION.tar.gz
```

Error:

```
Connecting to ftp.gnu.org (208.118.235.20:443)
wget: can't connect to remote host (208.118.235.20): Operation timed out
```

I have tried many variants like adding .wgetrc file within export https_proxy="" or adding parameter to wget command:
wget -Y on

No one of them works..

PS: wget with e option doesn't exists:

*wget: unrecognized option: e*

Answer (score -2):

If you have connectivity with your host, just add to your docker-compose file:

```
- network_mode: host
```

And you'll have inside the container the same interfaces, ports etc than in the host, without having to modify resolv.conf